# Pass button event to custom template

Tags: angular

I have a custom HTML template that I want to re-use. I am trying to pass a button event to the template but am not sure why it doesn't work. here is my code. I have created a stackblitz of it as well here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-oqokba?file=src/app/avaf-info/avaf-info.component.html

Code

AVAF-info component html

```
<information-template
  [data]="{
      templateBody: [
      {
        templateBodyHeader: 'accountInfo.label.advanceAmount',
        bodyHeaderLink: 'Adjust my loan '+ onLinkClick()
      }
      ]}"
>
</information-template>
```

AVAF-info component TS

```
onLinkClick() {
  this.openPanel = true;
}
```

Re-usable component html

```
<div class="template-container">
  <!-- Template body header .template-body-header + Link -->
  <div *ngIf="data.templateBody">
    <div *ngFor="let templateBody of data.templateBody" class="template-body-header-container">
      <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayoutAlign.gt-xs="space-between center"
        [ngClass]="{'template-body-indent-section': templateBody.indentSection}"
        [ngClass.gt-xs]="{'template-body-indent-section_gt-xs': templateBody.indentSection}">
        <div *ngIf="templateBody.bodyHeaderLink" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign.gt-xs="center end">
          <a class="body-header-link" tabindex="0" [attr.href]="" (keydown)="onLinkClickKeyDown($event, 'id')"
            (click)="onLinkClick($event, 'id')">{{templateBody.bodyHeaderLink}}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Re-usable component TS

```
  @Input() data?: InformationTemplateData;
  @Output() linkEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() buttonEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  onLinkClickKeyDown(e, linkId) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 32) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      this.onLinkClick(e, linkId);
    }
  }

  onLinkClick(e, linkId): void {
    const object = {
      linkId: linkId
    }
    this.linkEmitter.emit(object);
  }

  onButtonClick(event, id): void {
    const object = {
      event: event,
      buttonId: id
    }
    this.buttonEmitter.emit(object);
  }
```

I am not sure how I can append my button event to the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you are calling `(click)="onButtonClick()"` anywhere in your template, I can only see `(click)="onLinkClick()"`. Perhaps just a simple mistake! :)

Comment: How would I get onButtonClick into my template?

Comment: In the same way that you have already used `(click)="onLinkClick()"` inside the existing anchor tag, except you would attach it to the element you want to be clickable. Something like <button (click)="onButtonClick($event, id)">{{ buttonText }}</button>.